# LDAP Authentication for Native API in MobileFirst Platform Foundation

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am looking for reference and tutorial of MobileFirst Platform Foundation provided LDAP authentication.

AFAIK and as far as I can get from sources out there, MFPF provides LDAP auth for hybrid app only as can be read from [here](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/08_05_Using_LDAP_Login_Module_to_authenticate_user_with_LDAP_server.pdf).

I followed [this](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/hello-world/creating-first-native-android-mobilefirst-application/) tutorial to create native API and import all MFPF jar into native project and tried to import `com.worklightcore.auth.ext.ldapLoginModule` as seen from example code in hybrid below, but can't.

Does Worklight supports LDAP auth for native?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to import it where? What exactly did you try to import?

This is all server-side, so while the sample project contains a Hybrid application - the LDAP part is a server-side component (as it is defined in the authenticationConfig.xml file) and is valid for native apps as well.

Be it Hybrid or Native, both would communicate with the server via an adapter.
Be it Hybrid or Native, the adapter and any server-side configuration, including LDAP, is done in the MobileFirst project in Eclipse, and not in the native project (Xcode, Android Studio and so on).

You will need to better illustrate what you have done.
Even better, provide your native project for later debugging.

You can also take the LDAP sample project and keep it as-is.

Only add a NativeAPI, copy over the *SDK files* into your native project and implement in the native app the same client-side code done in the Hybrid app (adapter calls, logic, if there's a challenge handler then that as well).

Comment: After reading your answer, I realized that all the codes are in server side. Thanks!